# How to do one-tailed test of proportion vs. known proportion with repeated measures (GEE, power analysis)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion, statistical-power, generalized-estimating-equations

I may be over-complicating this, but I'm looking for advice.  Effectively, the question can boil down to something like: "How likely is it that people answer less than 90% of the questions from a bank of questions (in)correctly?"

The study design basically involves asking a group of (we'll say 20 for now) people to answer 10 questions each, randomly selected from the bank of questions.  Thus I have 20 x 10 = 200 binary outcome measures--but, of course, the responses from each individual may be correlated.  To account for this correlation, from what I have read, this requires the use of general estimating questions.  Is this correct?  Are there preferred, simpler ways to do this? (For example, I know I can just drop all but 1 observation from each individual, and that eliminates the repeated measures, but loses a lot of data; alternately, I can average each individual's scores, i.e., get their percent correct, but I'm not sure what analysis follow from there.)

In fact, I do not have any data, since I'm actually working on the power analysis.  How would I go about estimating the power required for the study?